What did Mirimanoff say about Intuitionism?
Dmitry Mirimanoff, "L'intuitionisme", Alma Mater n° 6, Geneva,  1945.
Most of Mirimanoff's work was in number theory, but he wrote three papers about set theory that were way ahead of their time. The first is called Les Antinomies de Russell et de Burali-Forti, et le Problème Fondemental de la Théorie des Ensembles and I have just translated it into English.
Given the depth of his insight into set theory, I am intrigued to find out what he had to say about Intuitionism, particularly as 1945 was somewhat after Brouwer's original work and before Heyting's formalisation of it.
The title of this question was originally about where to find this journal, but Sam Hopkins' comment gave me the full title, from which more information can be obtained:
Alma mater; revue universitaire de la Suisse romande
Editions Dixi, Genève, 1944-7, 32 issues.
ISSN 0256-5625
WorldCat says that it is available in several Swiss university libraries and
elsewhere:

Bibliothèque nationale de France
University libraries of Groningen, Navarra and Padova
University libraries of Harvard, Wisconsin and Yale
New York Public Library

There does not seem to be an online scanned version.

https://search.library.wisc.edu/catalog/999575719002121 ?
